# Get function result instead of "<function1>"

Tags: scala

I'm having a little trouble understanding passing functions as arguments in Scala. Here's what I'm doing:

```
class Foo1(f:Foo2) {
  def getFunResult(result:Foo2 => Int) = result
}

case class Foo2(bar:Int)
val a = Foo2(3)

println( new Foo1(a).getFunResult(_.bar) )
```

But this only prints out: `<function1>` and not `3`

How can I get `..getFunResult(_.bar)` to give me the result `3`?

Comment: What is the definition of type `A`? This won't compile. However you are returning `result` without invoking, so the string representation of the input function is being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never applying the function that you are passing to `getFunResult`. Try this

```
class Foo1[A](a: A) {
  def getFunResult(result:A => Int) = result(a)
}

case class Foo2(bar:Int)
val a = Foo2(3)

println( new Foo1(a).getFunResult(_.bar) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `getFunResult` returns the parameter it takes without doing anything with it

`result` is a parameter with the signature `A => Int` meaning a function that can take any value and returns an integer. Similarly, the signature of getFunResult is also `A => Int` and not `Int` as you might expect; this is because you aren't actually calling the function, you're just returning it.

In order to call it you need a parameter, a good example is like this:

```
def eval[A,B](f: A => B, a: A): B = f(a)
def eval[A,B](f: A => B) = f

def isEven(a: Int): Boolean = a % 2 == 0


// returns false
eval(isEven, 3) 
// returns <function1> because the function you passed didn't have any parameter
eval(isEven)
```

A way to solve your problem is by doing this:

```
class Foo1[A](a: A) {
  // it's good practice to include the return type in methods, 
  // that way you're sure to get a compiler error in case you make a 
  // mistake like the one you did
  def getFunResult(result: A => Int): Int = result(a) 
}

case class Foo2(bar:Int)
val a = Foo2(3)

println( new Foo1(a).getFunResult(_.bar) )
```